# Need help removing duplicates numbers in Python exercise

Tags: python, numbers, duplicates

I'm supposed to write a program that eliminates duplicate values and returns unique numbers. I must use a `def eliminate(alist)` and a `def main()`. The numbers must be entered from standard input and must be space separated.

The output should be as follow

> Enter numbers: 5 3 12 3 544 5 1 7 1
>
> The numbers are: [5, 3, 12, 554, 1, 7]

Instead I get....

> Enter numbers: 5 3 12 3 544 5 1 7 1
>
> The numbers are: ['5', ' ', '3', '1', '2', '4', '7']

How do I remove the space? Also my program doesn't recognize 554 as a single number, it recognizes it as 5 4 4.

This is what I got so far

```
def eliminate(alist):
    outlist = []
    for element in alist:
        if element not in outlist:
            outlist.append(element)
    return outlist       

def main():
    numbers=input("Enter numbers:")
    alist=list(numbers)
    print("The unique numbers are:",eliminate(alist))
main()
```

PLEASE NOTE: I'm not allow to use the set class for this program.

Comment: written a new answer with explanation

Comment: Did you try examining `alist` before you process it? What were you expecting it to contain? What does it contain? Can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the problems will be solved if you used:

```
alist = numbers.split()
```

instead of `alist=list(numbers)`

```
>>> numbers = '5 3 12 3 544 5 1 7 1'
>>> alist = numbers.split()
>>> alist
['5', '3', '12', '3', '544', '5', '1', '7', '1']
```

Explanation:

if you pass numbers to the list() function as is, it takes each character of the string to a list member. This way, '544' becomes ['5', '4', '4'] and '5 6' becomes ['5', '6'].

split() on the other hand makes list of a string by splitting it according to a specific delimiter, which is by default, the " " char.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation very detailed but the only thing left that is wrong is that it should come out without ''. Example [1,2,3]

Comment: In this case you can add the following command to convert it to integers:
`>>> alist = map(int, alist)`

Comment: This work. Are there other ways to convert it to an integer? because in my class we have not learned about map yet.

Answer (score 2):

You're just giving it a series of characters, and asking for unique ones, which it seems to be doing correctly.  You need to split the string on spaces, and maybe even convert to numbers (int's, I'm guessing):

```
alist = [int(num) for num in numbers.split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
item for item in myList if item.count(item) == 1
```

for the logic of your function body (if you must use it).  pass the return of this list comprehension to a variable or print.

Comment: What you're looking at doing is a simple one-line list comprehension.  You more or less have the same logic in your current eliminate(x) function.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting '' and 544 as separate characters because in your input, the `numbers` is not a list of integers. It is a string of characters. Even if you convert it to a list, it is still a list of individual characters.
So, for converting it into integers, do this:

`numbers=map(lambda x:int(x), numbers.split())`

Now, to eliminate the duplicates, you can use a dictionary, if not a set:

`unique = dict.fromkeys(numbers).keys()`